# Getting keys with duplicate values in a Groovy map

Tags: list, groovy, dictionary, key

I just came up with this problem while exploring groovy, I have a Map and i wanted to get the keys with the same values from that map.

```
Map maps = ['a': 10, 'b': 10, 'c': 11, 'd': 12]
```

is it possible to get only the keys with same values, what i wanted to get from this example is a list with values:

```
List keys = ['a','b']
```

I have a solution for this problem and it's a long line of codes, I'm just wondering if it is possible to solve this using `findAll` in Map. I'm having a hard time counting the values in the map.

thanks for sharing your ideas.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're asking for.  What do you want back in the case of `['a': 10, 'b': 10, 'c': 11, 'd': 12, 'e':12]`?  Also, note that your syntax is illegal - do you mean `[['a': 10], ['b': 10], ['c': 11], ['d': 12]]`, or what Anarchofascist below is proposing?  Also, do you know the specific values you're looking for ahead of time, or are you just looking for any key that has a duplicate value across the maps?

Comment: oh. i didn't know my syntax is illegal since it's working for me. thanks for the info. I want to retrieve the keys with duplicate values across the maps. in my example, i want to get the keys a & b since they have the duplicate values 10.

Comment: Correction: Syntax was only bad for a List.  It's fine now as a Map.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *know* which value you need the keys for, then you can use the `findAll` method to get all the entries that have that value and then get the keys with `keySet` or by using the splat operator as `*.key`:

```
def keysForValue(map, value) {
    map.findAll { it.value == value }*.key
}

def map = ['a': 10, 'b': 10, 'c': 11, 'd': 12]

assert keysForValue(map, 10) == ['a', 'b']
assert keysForValue(map, 12) == ['d']
assert keysForValue(map, 13) == []
```

---

In case you don't know which value should have the repeated keys, and all you want is to get the keys that have a repeated value (if there's any), you can try something like:

```
def getKeysWithRepeatedValue(map) {
    map.groupBy { it.value }.find { it.value.size() > 1 }?.value*.key
}
```

It first groups the map entries by value, so the result of `map.groupBy { it.value }` for the example map is `[10:[a:10, b:10], 11:[c:11], 12:[d:12]]`. Then it finds the first entry in that map that has a list with more than one element as a value; that entry corresponds with the value that has more than one key associated with it. The result of `.find { it.value.size() > 1 }` would be the map entry `10={a=10, b=10}`. The last conditional navigation and splat operator `?.value*.key` is to get the value of that entry in case it exists and then get keys of that value. Usage:

```
assert getKeysWithRepeatedValue(['a': 10, 'b': 10, 'c': 11, 'd': 12]) == ['a', 'b']

// If no value has more than one key, returns null:
assert getKeysWithRepeatedValue(['a': 10, 'c': 11, 'd': 12]) == null

// If more than one value has repeated keys, returns the keys that appear first:
assert getKeysWithRepeatedValue(['a': 10, 'b': 11, 'c': 10, 'd': 11]) == ['a', 'c']
```

Comment: that's very informative, i understand now how it works. thanks!

Comment: `groupBy` is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You mean

```
Map maps = ['a': 10, 'b': 10, 'c': 11, 'd': 12]
```

perhaps?  Easy enough, but a map does not preserve the ordering of elements. You can retrieve a list of keys in no particular order with:

```
List output = maps.keySet() as List
```

Or if you want to reverse the map, and find a list of keys for each value, you can use this:

```
Map output = maps.groupEntriesBy {
   it.value
}.each {
   it.value = it.value.collect {
      it.key
   }
}
```

Comment: side note: In your example you set the map from a literal, which in groovy converts to a LinkedHashMap, which does in fact preserve the order of the keys. My point was that if you got a map from somewhere other than a literal (or a LinkedHashMap) you cannot predict the order of "...keySet() as List".

Comment: hhmmm.. what i really want to get is the key that has duplicate values. so in my example. i want to return keys a & b because they have the same values 10.

Comment: Oh? Let me revise my answer then.